# compare values in 2 excel sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a formula to look at any value in Column D on Sheet1 and compare it with any value in Column D on Sheet2 and if there is a match put TRUE in Column H in the row of the match of Sheet2. The Data does not match per cell# such as D3 Sheet1 = D3 Sheet2. It might be D3 Sheet1 = D2487 Sheet2.

Comment: `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(D1,Sheet2!D:D,0))`.

Comment: I put this in column H of sheet2 and it worked. Maybe I didn't formulate the question correctly, anyways. =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$D:$D,MATCH($D2,Sheet1!$D:$D,0),1),"")

Answer (score 0):

Good morning man I think I have the solution for your problem:
[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gju42.png)In the first cell of column H where you want to compare the values you'll write this